# load event not firing when loading an image

Tags: javascript, html, onload

```
<template>
  <div>
    <canvas ref="myCanvas" class="gameScreen"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'GameScreen',
  data() {
    return {
      canvas: null,
      context: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.canvas = this.$refs.myCanvas;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    const img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener('load', () => {
      this.context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    }, false);
    img.src = '../assets/tiles.png';
  },
};
</script>
```

onload function is not being fired, I tried puting console statements in the function. can someone please tell me what I have done wrong

Comment: Are you sure the image URL is correct, otherwise `load` event won't trigger. Add an `error` event and check the response.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <canvas ref="myCanvas" class="gameScreen"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import image from './assets/logo.png';
export default {
  name: "GameScreen",
  data() {
    return {
      canvas: null,
      context: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.canvas = this.$refs.myCanvas;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    const img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener("load", () => {
      console.log("I am inside load");
      this.context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    });
    img.addEventListener("error", (err) => {
      console.log("error", err);
    });
    img.src = image;
  },
};
</script>
```

If the relative path didn't work, then can you try importing it first and using it. This worked for me.